# declaring objects in root scope of nodejs/commonjs modules - to var or not to var?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Maybe it's habit, or perhaps it's for consistency, but why is `var` used in the root scope of a module so much (many code examples show it)? Is it really necessary? I mean the module is root scope so whether you declared a variable with or without `var`, your attaching it to the same object in both situations, right? You aren't cluttering up any namespace, no?

```
qs = require('querystring'); // looks better than

var qs = require('querystring'); // right?
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with node.js, but without `var`, it's global.

Comment: If it's in the global scope, `var` won't really make a difference. Leaving it off might give those `require` statements more of an `import`-y look.

Comment: @Daedalus That's not true. var doesn't make something 'global' it traverses up the function scopes. Take for example this code.

`(function() {
  var foo;
  (function(){
    foo = 'bar';      
  })()
  console.log(foo);
})();
console.log(foo);`

The second console.log will be a ref error because foo is not defined.

Comment: @kennethkoontz Read my post again, that isn't what I said.

Comment: @daedalus Sorry, I meant if you don't use var, it doesn't make it global.

Comment: @kennethkoontz [Actually, it does](http://jsfiddle.net/tVB2u/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that Common JS modules are not only used in node.js but also in a variety of other environments.

Many Common JS modules can be used in browsers as well. Each module gets its own function wrapper to isolate it from other modules. In that case it's necessary to use `var` so that you don't accidentally leak into the global scope.

That being said most developers prefer to use `var` explicitly in their code for the following reasons:

1. It's a good programming practice. Seriously, programming is all about practice. I'm so used to declaring variables using `var` that I often find myself using `var` declarations in C/C++ and then have the compiler cry at me.
2. Variables declared using `var` cannot be deleted using the `delete` operator. Sometimes I purposely omit `var` in global variables so that I can delete them later and operate in "ninja mode".